# Rx.Net GroupBy implementation missing element sequence rarely

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx.net

I am using RX 2.2.5. I have 2 views which load sub orders with

```
           _transportService
            .ObserveSubOrder(parentOrder.OrderId)
            .SubscribeOn(_backgroundScheduler)
            .ObserveOn(_uiScheduler)
            .Where(subOs => subOs != null)                
            .Snoop("BeforeGrpBy")
            .GroupBy(subOs => subOs.OrderId)
            .Subscribe(subOrdUpdates =>
            {
                AddIfNew(subOrdUpdates.Key, subOrdUpdates.Snoop("AfterGrpBy" + "--" + subOrdUpdates.Key));                        
            })
```

Before groupBy it get all the sequence of elements, problem comes after groupby that it misses very rarely the element sequence. I don't think its concurrency issue as it's evident from the logs. Custom Snoop extension method is used to generate these logs.

```
16:15:44.8169968 : (1) : BeforeGrpBy: OnNext({ OrderId = 9Zsj8Z4sTRb, OrderType = WNX6, Quantity = 10, Price = 178.78125})
16:15:44.8169968 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Observable obtained
16:15:44.8369988 : (9) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Subscribed to on.
16:15:44.8379989 : (1) : BeforeGrpBy: OnNext({ OrderId = 9Zsj8Z4sTRb, OrderType = WNX6, Quantity = 10, Price = 178.78125})
16:15:44.8379989 : (9) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Subscription completed.
16:15:44.8590010 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Observable obtained
16:15:44.8600011 : (9) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Subscribed to on.
16:15:44.8610012 : (9) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: Subscription completed.
16:15:44.8620013 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--9Zsj8Z4sTRb: OnNext({ OrderId = 9Zsj8Z4sTRb, OrderType = WNX6, Quantity = 10, Price = 178.78125})
```

> Format Time : (Thread) : Msg

As you can see before groupby onNext is called twice, but after it missed one.
Is there something wrong with Rx grammar here or is it known issue? Any insight would help? If any further clarification is required kindly comment.

**Update:**
Adding working/desirable logs:

```
16:15:45.1070258 : (1) : BeforeGrpBy: OnNext({ OrderId = 44Fqp3ubNmL, OrderType = TTT6, Quantity = 39, Price = 130.21875})
16:15:45.1280279 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Observable obtained
16:15:45.1310282 : (10) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Subscribed to on.
16:15:45.1320283 : (10) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Subscription completed.
16:15:45.1320283 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: OnNext({ OrderId = 44Fqp3ubNmL, OrderType = TTT6, Quantity = 39, Price = 130.21875})
16:15:45.1330284 : (1) : BeforeGrpBy: OnNext({ OrderId = 44Fqp3ubNmL, OrderType = TTT6, Quantity = 39, Price = 130.21875})
16:15:45.1330284 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Observable obtained
16:15:45.1340285 : (10) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Subscribed to on.
16:15:45.1340285 : (10) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: Subscription completed.
16:15:45.1350286 : (1) : AfterGrpBy--44Fqp3ubNmL: OnNext({ OrderId = 44Fqp3ubNmL, OrderType = TTT6, Quantity = 39, Price = 130.21875})
```

**Update2:** Possible bug or feature

GroupBy fires the groupedObservable only if fireNewMapEntry is true, ([GroupBy.cs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/v2.2.5/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/GroupBy.cs#L129)) and this happens here

```
 if (!_map.TryGetValue(key, out writer))
 {
    writer = new Subject<TElement>();
    _map.Add(key, writer);
    fireNewMapEntry = true;
  }
```

where _map is of type `Dictionary<TKey, ISubject<TElement>>`. Is this could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just some notes on your code style (sorry, it isn't really an answer as I think @supertopi has answered)

1. Move you `SubscribeOn` and `ObserveOn` calls to be the last things you do before your final subscription. In you current code, you are executing the `Where`, the `Snoop` and the `GroupBy` all on the `_uiScheduler` taking up precious cycles.
2. Avoid subscribing with in a subscribe. It appears that `AddIfNew` takes a key and an `IObservable<T>`, thus I assume it is performing some subscription internally. Instead lean on what you know. If you are using the GroupBy, then you know the Key will be unique the first time a group is yielded. So this now can just be an Add (if it is the key you are checking). You can also use `Take(1)` if you want to be explicit. If it is the value not the key you are checking, well then the `GroupBy` appears to be redundant.
3. Try to keep you variable names consistent, so as another developer is reading through the query they are guided nicely, instead of jumping between `subOs`, `childOs` and `childUpdates`, when `childOrder` seems to be a better name (imo)
4. Ideally don't return null values in your observable sequence. What purpose does it serve? It may make sense in some rare occasions, but often I find that null is used instead of an `OnCompleted` to indicate that there are no values for this sequence.

e.g.

```
_transportService
        .ObserveSubOrder(parentOrder.OrderId)
        .Where(childOrder => childOrder != null)                
        .Snoop("BeforeGrpBy")
        .GroupBy(childOrder => childOrder.OrderId)
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Take(1).Select(childOrder=>Tuple.Create(grp.key, childOrder))
        .SubscribeOn(_backgroundScheduler)
        .ObserveOn(_uiScheduler)
        .Subscribe(newGroup =>
        {
            Add(newGroup.Item1, newGroup.Item2);                        
        },
          ex=>//obviously we have error handling here ;-)
        );
```

or

```
_transportService
        .ObserveSubOrder(parentOrder.OrderId)
        .Where(childOrder => childOrder != null)                
        .Snoop("BeforeGrpBy")
        .SubscribeOn(_backgroundScheduler)
        .ObserveOn(_uiScheduler)
        .Subscribe(childOrder =>
          {
             AddIfNew(childOrder.OrderId, childOrder);                             
          },
          ex=>//obviously we have error handling here ;-)
        );
```

and even better (without snoop and null checks)

```
var subscription = _transportService
        .ObserveSubOrder(parentOrder.OrderId)
        .SubscribeOn(_backgroundScheduler)
        .ObserveOn(_uiScheduler)
        .Subscribe(
          childOrder => AddIfNew(childOrder.OrderId, childOrder),
          ex=>//obviously we have error handling here ;-)
        );
```

hth

Comment: Taken ur point 3. For point 4. I have no control over generating of sequence in observable as its coming from different assembly in the framework. For point 2. Avoid subscribing with in a subscribe! (Whats d drawback here) Again point 1, Agreed it could be removed but again is it causing the issue of concurrency and thus missing of elements?

Comment: And actual implementation don't have Snoop, its just for debugging :) but do have null checking due above mentioned reason

Comment: Subscribing within a subscription means you are highly likely to be dropping subscriptions on the floor (and fumbling around trying not too), which means memory leaks. You also are highly likely to not have the additional layer of error handling. Instead compose flows in the query.

Comment: That's quiet a nice suggestion there, I am taking care of the higher order composition here by proper disposing. I am aware of the alternatives to this solution, but I am concerned why this situation is not working, logically I can't see any problem in semantics, apart from inner working of groupby

Comment: Most of the time when I see people getting "issues" like this with Rx, and they aren't following general guidance, the problems go away when they just "fall in line" with guidance. Without a repro it is very hard to help here. But as groupBy has been used alot for the 4yrs that version of Rx has been out, i doubt very much it is a bug with Rx

Comment: Sry for stretching this, do u mean guideline says we can't do higher order composition (i.e subscribing inside subscribe, could u provide the ref. or drawbacks). Here ForEg. AddIfNew takes IObservable<T> and is reusable with both parent and sub orders. All above eg. you mention will work f9 :) but then re-usability will be gone.

Comment: I would argue that you are dropping the composition of high order _rx_ functions (e.g. SelectMany/FlatMap/Bind). I would also argue that your code will be far more dificult to understand as I assume you must have a lot of mutable state to manage all of the inner subscription tokens. If you showed what your full code looks like then I am sure we can come up with a better design, find out what the bug really is, and fix it too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126878/discussion-between-mkmohanty-and-lee-campbell).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the nature of `GroupBy`.

The operator emits `OnNext` only after a new group appears (see implementation [GroupBy.cs:67](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/GroupBy.cs#L67)). In your case, the `orderID` equals for both notifications so only one `OnNext` is emitted.

The value emited by the operator is of `IGroupedObservable<T>` to which you can subscribe if you need access to further notifications within the group.

Comment: As i mentioned in question it is happening rarely, almost once in 100.. and if you see the logs after groupby, 2 different observable is obtained which should result in 2 different groupedObservable, and therefore i am expecting 2 onNext.. I will update the question with logs for working cases.

Comment: I suggest you take notes from @LeeCampbell to enhance your querys coding style. From your style of subscribing, there probably is a race condition hidden somewhere which produces the "randomness". I believe my answer is valid, since `GroupBy` of course produces new `IGroupedObsevable` for same key after the subscription has been disposed and continued again.